# File Watcher is giving error code 255 - Syntaxerror

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, gruntjs, phpstorm, file-watcher

I'm trying to get the IntelliJ / PhpStorm File Watcher to auto compile my SCSS via grunt.

Grunt itself seems to work fine, it works at least correctly if I call it via Terminal. But the File Watcher does not seems to like my configuration. Every time it gets triggered it gives me a Code 255 - Syntaxerror

I've tried multiple configuration for the File Watcher but none seems to work, what could be the error ?

[image: Screenshot from the error, the file watcher config and the folder structure]

Any Ideas what to put in here correctly for compiling the SCSS to CSS via grunt?

Und hier ist beiläufig noch die grunt.cmd, falls das hilft.

```
<TaskOptions>
  <TaskOptions>
    <option name="arguments" value="" />
    <option name="checkSyntaxErrors" value="true" />
    <option name="description" />
    <option name="exitCodeBehavior" value="ERROR" />
    <option name="fileExtension" value="scss" />
    <option name="immediateSync" value="true" />
    <option name="name" value="SCSS" />
    <option name="output" value="$ProjectFileDir$" />
    <option name="outputFilters"><array /></option>
    <option name="outputFromStdout" value="false" />
    <option name="program" value="$USER_HOME$/AppData/Roaming/npm/grunt" />
    <option name="runOnExternalChanges" value="true" />
    <option name="scopeName" value="recoruces" />
    <option name="trackOnlyRoot" value="true" />
    <option name="workingDir" value="$ProjectFileDir$" />
    <envs />
  </TaskOptions>
</TaskOptions>
```

Comment: huh, why is the Screenshot not shown directly, hmm ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, what a solution.

I have no idea why but after reinstalling grunt, the shown grunt.cmd looks now completly differnt. I have no Idea why some kind of xml was hidden in there now it seems to work ...